# Show complete workspace preview in gnome-shell activities

Tags: desktop, gnome

If I activate the *Activities* view in gnome-shell (e.g. by using the windows key) the preview of different workspaces at the right hand side is shown only partly (see first image below). I have to move the mouse over the previews in order to get them fully shown (see second image below).

I'd rather like the workspace previews to appear already fully if I activate the application overview.

**Any ideas on how to do this?**

This is gnome shell 3.28.1 as it comes with debian/buster/sid.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This extension may be the right one: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1351/show-workspaces/

A comment from that site how to achieve this without an extension:

> You can avoid having to install this extension with a small tweak of your Gnome Shell Theme, found either in: ~/.themes/CustomTheme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css (if you're using a custom theme) /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css (if you're using the crappy gnome/ubuntu one). Do a search for .workspace-thumbnails { You'll get two hits, go for the one that has a visible-width variable. Ex: .workspace-thumbnails { visible-width: 32px; spacing: 11px; padding: 8px; border-radius: 9px 0 0 9px; } .workspace-thumbnails:rtl { border-radius: 0 9px 9px 0; } change it visible-width from default value (32px) to something along the lines of 175px One less extension in your life.

Comment: According to the extension page, Gnome Shell 3.30 introduces this as the default behaviour.